Plotly Dash Dropdown set initial value to be item from row of data table
I would like to have a dropdown in my data table to be able to be changed to update a category component.  For example, if a category in the datatable is Groceries, I would like it to display that value initially, and then have the dropdown to be able to select a new category.  The Category2 column is the one I am trying to set for the dropdown, the category column is currently just for testing to make sure things match up.
categorieslist=[
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in df['Category'].unique()
                ]

dash_table.DataTable(
        id='adding-rows-table-UpdateTransaction',
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Date','id': 'Date'},
            {'name': 'Provider','id': 'Provider'},
        {'name': 'Amount','id': 'Amount'},
        {'name': 'Category','id': 'Category'},
{'id': 'Category2', 'name': 'Category2', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
        {'name': 'Note','id': 'Note'}],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        dropdown={
            'Category2': {
                'options': categorieslist,
                'value':data[]?
            },

        },
        row_deletable=True
    ),

I have tried several variations of the data dictionary, as well as the initial dataframe to find the specified value.  But it doesnt seem to come out
